# SFMC Programming Language - AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, developer

What are the best resources to learn AMPscript langauge for SFMC development? I would like to know more on how a SFMC beginner can start AMPScript learning and what are the common tools to use to practice AMPScript coding.

Comment: Trailhead should pretty much always be your first port of call for "how to do/use X on Salesforce?". https://trailhead.salesforce.com/search?keywords=ampscript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few good ones.

https://ampscript.guide/ - This is basically a more detailed version of the documentation
https://ampscript.xyz/ - This has more specific use cases, but a lot of good examples.
https://mc.chat/ - Eliot helped write the ampscript guide, he uses a lot of video if you prefer that

There are a few others you'll encounter as well. I always search for a specific thing and these come up, plus some others.